# How can a new client get socket data if it hasn't been emitted since connected

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I have googled for hours but cannot seem to find an answer.  I have clients emitting and listening to sockets, some change very frequent while others might only change every few minutes.  My question is when a new client connects (or connected client refreshes) how does it get the data from those that only change every few minutes before the server emits it?

Client code

```
var socket = io.connect();
socket.on('frequent', function(data){
    $frequent.text(data);
});
socket.on('occasional', function(data){
    $occasional.text(data);
});
```

Server code (Theoretically. The emits work fine are are not the problem)

```
io.emit('frequent', data);
io.emit('occasional', data);
```

Answer (score 0):

When a client connects to the server, the server can immediately send the current state of the data:

```
io.on('connection', function(socket) {
    socket.emit("status", currentData);
});
```

This way, the client gets the current status immediately and doesn't have to wait for the next change.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. So when and what is defining currentData?

Comment: @cTwice - whatever you want it to be.  The point of this code is to send the current state of the data to the client as soon as the client connects rather than make the client wait for the next event.  If the current state isn't already handy in your server, then you must save the data from the most recent event in a module variable so it is available when this code runs.